# Radiomic features

Tags: machine-learning

I have a specific problem that I am trying to solve on the topic of radiomic features. Briefly, radiomic features are quantitative features extracted from medical images, such as CT and MRI. let's say, my dataset has CT images scanned with 2 image acquisition parameters (tube current, tube voltage), the value ranges from 0 - 200 in both mAs and kVp. mAs and kVp are settings you need to set to take CT images using CT scanners.

I would want a ML model that corrects or shifts the data to an arbitrary level (it could be shifted to any parameter values, maybe median kVp and mAs?, so like 100 kVp and 100 mAs)..so I would want the ML model to transform all the feature values so that they are about the same, despite the values of kVp and mAs parameter....

From many studies, it is shown that using different settings in those two parameter can influence the radiomic feature values that are extracted from our CT images. So basically, those two parameters influence the feature values that I obtain. I am trying to find a way to correct the feature value using these two imaging parameters, i.e. mAs value of 20 and kVp value of 100... and mAs value of 50 and kVp value of 200 would return same value of radiomic feature from the image that I extracted. (the 2 pairs of values that I wrote here is arbitrary, in reality, it could be anything with increment of 10, let's say)

so basically, I need to train a machine learning algorithm that corrects the two parameters. So in the end, whichever parameter values I take from 0 - 200 in both mAs and kVp, the feature value I extract from CT images will result in the same value. I would like to hear ideas from the community on what algorithm I can use to tackle such problems.

Comment: Your question is interesting, but you may need to add a bit of code (jupyter notebook) and image (dicom) to help non-biomed ML folk potentially answer this question. Add details like, what is the ML model you want? Provide intuition of a radiomic feature? Off the top of my head, your problem sounds like Regression Analysis; axes are mAS and kVP. There is a curve in the (mAS,kVP) space that provides the 'optimal' radiomic feature for diagnostics that you can recover using Regression.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much! Radiomic features are quantitative features extracted from medical images, such as CT and MRI. I would want a ML model that corrects or shifts the data to an arbitrary level (it could be any, may be median kVp and mAs?) so that all the feature values are about the same. does that make more sense? Sorry I am new to stack exchange, I hope I can edit the original post...

Comment: While I'd more more information to be sure, it does sound like you need to do 'Standardization' or Z-score Normalization, which are part of Feature Scaling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). Intuition: F_mAS,kVP (CT) -> Radiomic. Unfortunately, you cannot compute inverse of F_mAS,kVP, so next best thing is to use statistical normalization, i.e. shift and scale radiomic features. (1) Histogram of lots of radiomics (population) (2) Gaussian Fit it, (3) sample CT: histogram and gaussian. (4) 'fit' sample gaussian to population gaussian. (4) Sample radiomic is corrected!

Comment: So, to make the problem little more complicated. we have CT machines that are produced by different companies (GE, Siemens etc). So these companies, even though have mAs and kVp settings, the way the machines are developed, they produce different CT images, so different radiomic feature values. I do like the idea of regression analysis. I think that would suit better for my project than simply standardization. In my next comment I will tell you more about the specifics of the project.

Comment: Basically, we make images of phantom A and B. these are just different textures that you can scan using CT scanners. So A and B should have different radiomic feature values. so we can scan A and B using different machines (GE and Siemens) using multiple increments of kVp and mAs. so we have now GE (mAs, kVp) trend and then Siemens (kVp and mAs) trend, those two needs to be standardize among each other as well. So final goal is, feature value extracted from phantom A scanned using GE with (mAs 20, kVp 30) = phantom A scanned with (Siemens kvp 100, mAs 30) numbers are arbitrary..

Comment: Furthermore, phantom B scanned with kVp x and mAs y with GE should match (close enough) to Siemens ones but phantom A and B should have different values since they are different textures. does that make sense? its a little complicated to explain! but I hope I did an ok job...

Comment: Check out Relative Radiometric Normalization (RRN). While the technique has been developed for normalizing satellite imagery, you might want to adopt it for CT. Although the analog of RRN would be for longitudinal studies, which is not what you want. Look into doing Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to de-correlate your radiomic features, then compute that regression between GE -> Siemens on the de-correlated features. Finally, if all else fails, there is always Generative Adversarial Networks to the rescue, but you'll need a lot of data.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will have a look at these techniques whether they work or not. You are a life saver! I will keep you posted!

Comment: Hi, what do you think about using deep learning to standardize medical images? I looked at relative radiometric normalization, however, working with medical images (dicom format) + grey scale image (not RGB) would require fair amount of adaptation to implement RNN. Using deep learning to standardize images across scanners will be an alternative way to RNN? I will look into PCA--> regression, that will be nice way to do it after I have extracted features from different images. I guess this method can be categorized under "standardization after features are extracted".

Comment: See cycle-GAN (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10593). There are other GANs to consider too, the choice is based on the data you have in hand.

Comment: thank you so much! I will definitely look into those. Another question, so the reason why we do PCA before regression analysis is to combine all the feature information (number of features ~100) into principal component (few principal components) and then do regression analysis to standardize. Can we invert back to principal component so that we have the transformed features?

Comment: there is a technique called principal component regression already, that applies regression analysis on the principal component of the data rather than original dataset. is it the same as method you suggested previously?

Comment: (1) Yes, PCR would be the thing to try (good find!). (2) As a course baseline, try local adaptive intensity histogram-equalization for vendor normalization. Analyze the box-plots of your radiomics from the equalized CTs. That way you'll know how much effort you want to devote to PCR. (3) The following paper on using cycle-gan for MRI vendor normalization (GE->Siemens and Siemens->GE) seems impressive in handling  both intensity and also noise: https://deepai.org/publication/normalization-of-breast-mris-using-cycle-consistent-generative-adversarial-networks

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I do think cycle-gan is very interesting. I am also reading that it is not widely used for 3-D images, which I am working with (dicom format), It does look like most of its application is based on 2D images. Am I correct that I will find PC for GE data and PC for Siemens data. Then I will do regression on the two PC and standardize them? I worked hard to understand the concept here but I am not entirely sure..

Comment: This is the basis of my study....here they only corrected radiomic feature for mAs (or exposure or tube current)...https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405630819300862